# Return Ajax success Object Using TypeScript for CRUD operation

Tags: ajax, typescript

I am trying to return value from success object via typescript. And don't seem to get how to do that. I tried it through callback function but it does not call it on success. Basically I need to return ajax success or error data back to edit method. In order to process it further.

```
class ProductsController {

    element:JQuery;
    url:string;
    token:string;
    action:string;
    id:number;
    data:Object;

    constructor(element:string) {
        this.element = $(element);
        this.url = this.element.attr('href');
        this.token = this.element.data('token');
        this.id = this.element.data('id');
        this.action = this.element.data('action');
    };

    ajaxRequest(request) {
        var self = this;
        $.ajax(request).done(function (results) {
            self.data = results;
        }).fail(function (error) {
            self.data = error;
        })

        return self.data;
    }

    edit() {
        return this.ajaxRequest({
            url: this.url,
            type: "get",
        })

    }
    update() {}
    del() {}

}
$(".product-act").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var el = new ProductsController(this);
    console.log(el.edit());
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: Return data after ajax call success](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success)

Comment: Hint: ajax originally stood for **Asynchronous** JavaScript And XML. The important part is "asynchronous". You're returning `self.data` before the results have come from the ajax call.

Comment: Possibly its typescript not standard JavaScript, would be great to know how to return it after. That is already understood and I can implement it by mean of standard javaScript. I am not sure how its done in TypeScript.

Comment: TypeScript compiles to JavaScript; it's the same problem.

Comment: Every "How do I do *X* at runtime in TypeScript?" question always has the same answer as for the JavaScript version of the same question.